# Flow of Jsp -> Javascript webpage (Ajax?)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I am making a website but I get a bit lost programming dynamic sites.

The user needs to enter x (inside a textbox), click submit, process in java (serverside) and present outcome as a report to the user (using javascript).

I'm at the moment using JSP to process the users input but now I need to pass the JSON code into the javascript. The javascript requires JSON data.

At the moment I have JSP which returns the necessary JSON code and the Javascript which works with hardcoded JSON code. I need to somehow store the returned JSON (from the JSP) in a variable and pass it to the Javascript. I have a vague understanding of AJAX - i'm just unsure if this is possible and how to link it all together.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP "page" can simply generate JSON directly. There's no reason the output from JSP has to be HTML. From the client, therefore, you POST to the server, the JSP runs, and the result (pure JSON from your JSP) is sent back to the client as the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect place for AJAX - you can submit the request with javascript, and when it comes back process it further with javascript.  Unless you want the page to refresh.

If you are using jQuery, you can look here to see how to implement it, should be relatively painless: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/